# Do I say "Au convaincre" or "convaincre lui" To mean I convince him

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

Does the *"le"* join to *"à"* to form *"au"* in *"Après Lin a échoué à convaincre"* or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, `à` does not join with `le` because `au` [is the contracted article.](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/au/)

But in the phrase,

> Lin a échoué à le convaincre

le is not an article but rather a personal pronoun (Lin convinced whom? him = le). It therefore remains `à le`.